# Anomaly in Curl Computation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, determinant, cross-product

Suppose computing the 3D curl of a vector field involves finding this determinant:

$$
\mathrm{det} \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\hat{i}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x}   & 7y^3z^2 \\
\mathbf{\hat{j}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  & xyz \\
\mathbf{\hat{k}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  & -3x-z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Using cofactor expansion, we should be able to break this into the subdeterminants obtained by excluding any row or column of our choice.  However, if we choose the right column, the determinant will incorrectly appear as $(7y^3z^2 - xyz + (-3x - z))\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$, the zero vector.

This is because the unit vectors have nothing but constant entries, thus their partial derivatives will always equal $\mathbf{0}$.  Choosing the left column is the sane route, while choosing the middle column appears to work, but choosing the right column leads to a different result.  How is this consistent with the typical rules of determinants?

Comment: It is not. The determinant method for computing the curl is merely a mnemonic and is only meant to be applied via the left column. The curl is not actually a determinant; the fact that the matrix contains entries like $\hat i$ and $\partial/\partial x$, which are not numbers, should give that away.

Comment: I think that at the least you can also use the middle column.

Comment: Writing the basis vectors in bold *and* with a hat is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use this method, you have to be careful to preserve the *order* of the terms at all times, because the "multiplication" is not commutative in this context! You must have a unit vector, followed by a partial derivative, followed by one of the polynomials in the right column. The partial derivative applies *only* to the polynomial, *not* to the unit vector. The unit vector just comes along for the ride. In particular, the following is incorrect:

> This is because the unit vectors have nothing but constant entries, thus their partial derivatives will always equal the 0 vector.

Let's say we exclude the right column, as you did. Then, for the $7x^2y^2$ term, the correct computation is:

$$j \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 7x^2y^2 - k \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 7x^2y^2$$
which equals $-k (14x^2y)$.

Now repeat for the other two factors in the third column.

Comment: Aren't the columns required to be commutative up to the determinant's sign?  If we swapped columns 1 and 2, then the partial differential operator would be eating the unit vectors once again.  How can the order be decided systematically if we don't already know what the solution should look like?

Comment: No, in this non-commutative context, the usual rule for swapping columns (or rows) in the determinant doesn't apply. The original formula is a correct method for computing the curl only if the columns are ordered in this way.